# Triggering swipe and touch events on a mobile web app? - iPhone/Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone, dom-events

Wondering  if there **is a way I could *trigger* an event, so that any library listening for these events** (e.g. jQTouch, Sencha touch, iUI, ... ).

If I could extend or use jQuery for such task e.g. `$(...).trigger('event')` that would be great to know.

---

**Usage example:**

I need to debug a few web apps by simulating multi touch with my mouse. This seems a little complicated, so if I could trigger the multi-touch events using Javascript I could therefore test the app more efficiently.

---

Any ideas?

Comment: is that you on the profile picture :p ?

Comment: @jAndy: lol... focus! =)

Comment: I'm so focused. That's not an answer anyway :) To your problem here, I don't think I get it. Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is in webkit, but it may be useful:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent

Lets you fire events such as 'click', so if the function exists in webkit then it should also work for touch events.

Comment: Thanks for this! It would be really good to know if it works with multi touch events. I'm gonna have a good look at this thanks again!! =)

Comment: Note that Android does not currently support multitouch events: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableTouch.html

Answer (score 2):

The [Android Code Monkey](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html) might already do what you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll check it out =) A javascript library that can be run from within the webpage would awesome.

Comment: Wait, you mean a webpage that runs javascript to simulate user input?

Comment: said like that it sounds like a silly question :) It's just that I don't know how to go on about multi-touch.

Comment: No silliness intended :) I was just trying to better define the question after noticing you wanted a solution that worked on not just Android. I don't think JavaScript is given rights (by the Browser/OS) to inject user inputs into a device's keyboard/touch/mouse input buffer. You may have some success with a custom "test harness" app, but it probably can't be written in JS :/